# Set a value based on current build/flavor settings

Tags: android, groovy, gradle

I need to set a value in my build script based on which flavor I am building.  Here are the relevant parts of my current `build.gradle`:

```
android {
    // ...
    productFlavors {
        lite {
            applicationId "bbct.android"
            versionCode 15
            versionName "0.6.2"
        }
        premium {
            applicationId "bbct.android.premium"
            versionCode 14
            versionName "0.6.2"
        }
    }
}

testdroid {
    mode 'FULL_RUN'
    projectName 'BBCT Lite'

    fullRunConfig {
        instrumentationRunner = 'android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner'
    }
}
```

Now I want to set `testdroid.projectName` to different values depending on whether I build the `lite` or `premium` flavor. I tried the following:

```
android {
    // ...
    productFlavors {
        lite {
            applicationId "bbct.android"
            versionCode 15
            versionName "0.6.2"
            testdroid.projectName = "BBCT Lite" // here
        }
        premium {
            applicationId "bbct.android.premium"
            versionCode 14
            versionName "0.6.2"
            testdroid.projectName = "BBCT Premium" // and here
        }
    }
}
```

However, this unconditionally assigns `testdroid.projectName` to `"BBCT Premium"`. (I assume because the last line executed sets it to this value.) How do I set `testdroid.projectName` to the correct value depending on my build flavor?

Comment: A Gradle build script is not building a project. Primarily, it is building an object model that describes how to build the project. Hence, when you are running the script, both the `lite {}` and `premium {}` closures are executed. Similarly, your `testdroid` closure is executed to build the object model, and there is no build flavor at that point. I haven't used the Testdroid plugin, so I don't know what tasks it creates, but if it creates per-flavor tasks, that's a starting point for figuring out how to configure those tasks with your desired project name.

Comment: @CommonsWare The testdroid plugin does in fact create tasks for each flavor: `testdroidUploadliteDebug` and `testdroidUploadpremiumDebug`. How do I use this to set the correct value for the `projectName`?

Answer (score 1):

As already explained in the comment, when building your buildscript both terms get evaluated and the latter one sets the value.

To do this, you can make use of the `ext` object that every task / item has. If you assign your value to it, you can later execute the right step in your actual build.

The following is one way to do it, and there sure is a better way to do this using `afterEvaluate` or something, but this works for me in a similar usecase.

```
android {
    productFlavors {
        lite {
            applicationId "bbct.android"
            versionCode 15
            versionName "0.6.2"
            ext.projectName = "BBCT Lite" // here
        }
        premium {
            applicationId "bbct.android.premium"
            versionCode 14
            versionName "0.6.2"
            ext.projectName = "BBCT Premium" // and here
        }
    }
}
preBuild << {
    android.applicationVariants.all { variant ->
        variant.productFlavors.each { flavor ->
            resValue "string", "projectName", flavor.ext.projectName
            testdroid.projectName = flavor.ext.projectName
        }
    }
}
```